# Using same images in different content and products

Tags: commerce, media

I am developing a website and on the homepage I have an add to cart form as well as a carousel which use the same images.

I am also re-using certain images for several types of products in Commerce.

Is there a method of using the same image rather than uploading a new one each time as I am thinking this will save bandwidth on page-load

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you want different size variations of the same image for the different section of your website.

[Imagekit.io](https://imagekit.io) can help you resize images just by passing width in the URL. This will allow you to store just one big image on your server and deliver smaller size variations as per the layout. There is some automatically advanced optimization as well which will help you save bandwidth on page-load.